# start redis with supervisor

Tags: redis, supervisord

When start redis with supervisor, the redis process is running, but in supervisor it shows backoff.

```
vagrant@jinming:~$ sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/conf/supervisor/supervisord.conf
redis                            BACKOFF   Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

in supervisor log, it shows below:

```
2015-06-09 07:09:28,407 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-06-09 07:09:28,407 WARN Included extra file "/etc/conf/supervisor/conf.d/redis_local.conf" during parsing
2015-06-09 07:09:28,407 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-06-09 07:09:28,407 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-06-09 07:09:28,407 INFO supervisord started with pid 23191
2015-06-09 07:09:29,410 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 23332
2015-06-09 07:09:29,416 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-06-09 07:09:30,418 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 23334
2015-06-09 07:09:30,425 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-06-09 07:09:32,429 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 23336  
2015-06-09 07:09:32,434 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-06-09 07:09:36,067 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 23342
2015-06-09 07:09:36,072 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-06-09 07:09:37,073 INFO gave up: redis entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2015-06-09 07:11:04,079 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-06-09 07:11:04,079 WARN Included extra file "/etc/conf/supervisor/conf.d/redis_local.conf" during parsing
2015-06-09 07:11:04,080 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-06-09 07:11:04,080 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-06-09 07:11:04,080 INFO supervisord started with pid 23191
2015-06-09 07:11:05,083 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 23486
2015-06-09 07:11:05,089 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
```

anyone can help me, thanks.

Comment: I figure it out , just set daemonize no and then start redis with supervisor.

Comment: Hi,
Can you tell me what is your /etc/conf/supervisor/conf.d/redis_local.conf configuration? I can't seem to pass the path to the /etc/redis/redis.conf to the executable file and have supervisor start redis successfully. Thanks!

Comment: @einarc, it's just redis configuration file and you can start supervisor with sudo and start redis with sudo too, maybe this can help you.

Comment: I figured the issue was that the redis binary wasn't starting the service because of a configuration problem on the redis.conf file. Once that was fixed supervisor was able to load redis correctly. No changes were necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using Supervisord to manage server programs like databases that often spawn or daemonize, look for a flag in the startup command or in the config file. There is an exception with databases like MySQL where recommended practice is to use a proxy to start mysqld_safe and let it manage the sub processes.

In `redis.conf` for newer versions (i.e. 3.x) the default is to disable daemon but it may have been edited by your package. Also be sure you didn't install with an upstart script that will respawn.

## Redis config file section

```
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' if you need it.
# Note that Redis will write a pid file in /var/run/redis.pid when daemonized.
daemonize no
```

## Example Supervisor configs

- https://gist.github.com/ehazlett/1817619
- https://github.com/calvdee/docker-redis/blob/master/supervisord.conf

Comment: I left a comment on another solution below, but it's worth noting here that something strange is happening. Without a spec'd config file, Redis uses its default configuration. However, this is *not* using the default config file. The default configuration specs `daemonize no` whereas the default configuration file (`/etc/redis/redis.conf`) specs `daemonize yes`. My thinking is that the best solution is to use the configuration file, but update it to have `daemonize no`.

Comment: Please note the post is 5 years old and things may have changed, however you'll see "but it may have been edited by your package" so yes, it's best to be explicit and set it to what you desire. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## Problem

`redis-server` is not working with below `supervisord.conf`

Especially, `redis-server` command with conf file location argument

#### redis-server --version

```
Redis server v=2.8.17 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=5b70b85861dcf95e
```

#### supervisord.conf

```
[program:redis-server]
command=redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf # PLEASE NOTE THIS LINE
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
stdout_logfile=/var/log/redis/stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/redis/stderr.log
```

#### my_redis.conf

```
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' if you need it.
# Note that Redis will write a pid file in /var/run/redis.pid when daemonized.
daemonize no
```

#### Dockerfile

```
RUN cp -f my_redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf &&\
```

#### supervisorctl

[image: supervisorctl status]

#### Test via command line

[image]

## Solution

Without custom conf file location, everything works well.

In my case, I overwrote default conf in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` with `my_redis.conf`

```
[program:redis-server]
command=redis-server # JUST REMOVE EXTRA CONF FILE LOCATION, EVERYTHING WORKS WELL
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
stdout_logfile=/var/log/redis/stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/redis/stderr.log
```

ps. Is there bug at this redis version? or my conf is wrong?

Comment: What's happening here is that when Redis is started without a config file, it does *not* deamonize (ie. `daemonize no`). But, the default / included config file *does* daemonize (ie. `daemonize yes`). This solution will use Redis' default config, not the default configuration file. A better solution is is to update keep the config file specified, and update it to include `daemonize no`.